# Save attachment from gMail to gDrive?

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried the following script but got an error.  Any suggestions?

```
function saveAttachmentInGDrive(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var userId = "myemail@gmail.com";
  var query = "label:Test";

  var attA=GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id).getAttachments();
  attA.forEach(function(a){
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyMMddHHmmss");
    folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName()+ts);
  });
}
```

Comment: The variable `m.id` is not defined.

Comment: What error did you get? You can [edit] your question to show us.

Comment: This example is not a [mcve].